# Как можно узнать на какую ячейку UniformGrid кликнули?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как можно узнать, на какую ячейку `UniformGrid` кликнули?

```
<UniformGrid Rows="3" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}">
    <Label Background="Red"></Label>
    <Label Background="Green"></Label>
    <Label Background="Blue"></Label>
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: Обрабатывать клик на лейбле - не вариант?

Comment: @Monk,  не вариант.

Comment: @Lightness: Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простого и быстрого пути нет. Можно только за O(n).

```
private void UniformGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // узнаем, на каком элементе кликнули
    var element = e.Source as UIElement;
    if (element != null)
    {
        // узнаем индекс этого элемента среди всех контролов грида
        int index = UniformGrid.Children.IndexOf(element);
        // узнаем ряд и колонку
        int row = index / UniformGrid.Columns;
        int column = index % UniformGrid.Columns;
    }
}
```

---

Возможно, что будет лучше пойти по пути MVVM, где содержимое будет заполняться через биндинг и где номер ячейки вы будете контролировать сами.

Comment: Поскольку в нашем случае n == 3 (и исходя из задачи, разумно предположить, что N < 1000), то О(1). Если очень нужно быстро отображать элемент в индекс, можно повесить этот индекс один раз в Tag.

Comment: @VladD разумно.

Comment: @andreycha, спасибо, именно это мне и нужно.

Comment: @Lightness не за что!