# Привязка коллекции к большому количеству контролов

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Допустим у меня есть массив строк [3,3] и UniformGrid внутри которого 9 шт. Label. Как привязать каждый элемент массива к определенному Label? Или создавать для каждой элемента свойство и привязываться к каждому Label?

```
<UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" x:Name="myGrid"}"
                <Label></Label>
                <Label></Label>
                <Label></Label>
                <Label></Label>
                <Label></Label>
                <Label></Label>
                <Label></Label>
                <Label></Label>
                <Label></Label>
    </UniformGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто!

Вот вам пример.

1. XAML. Здесь идея в том, что для Binding'а на список элементов вам нужен `ItemsControl`. А для расположения его как в `UniformGrid` нужно переопределить `ItemsPanel`:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="SO8WPF.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO8WPF"
           Title="Binding to uniform grid" Height="350" Width="525">
       <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
           <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="3" IsItemsHost="True"/>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <Label Content="{Binding Text}">
                       <Label.Background>
                           <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
                       </Label.Background>
                   </Label>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       </ItemsControl>
   </Window>
   ```
2. Теперь view model. Мы берём стандартную имплементацию INPC, ничего особенного.

   ```
   public class ItemVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       string text;
       public string Text
       {
           get { return text; }
           set { if (text != value) { text = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
       }

       Color color;
       public Color Color
       {
           get { return color; }
           set { if (color != value) { color = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
       }

       void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   }
   ```
3. Кладём VM-ки в плоский список. Если реально нужна индексация с двумя индексами, делаем это отдельно.

   ```
   class MainVM
   {
       public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> Items { get; } =
           new ObservableCollection<ItemVM>()
           {
               new ItemVM() { Text = "Fünf", Color = Colors.Chocolate },
               new ItemVM() { Text = "Sechs", Color = Colors.DarkSlateBlue },
               new ItemVM() { Text = "Alte", Color = Colors.Maroon },
               new ItemVM() { Text = "Hex", Color = Colors.LawnGreen },

               new ItemVM() { Text = "Sieben", Color = Colors.DeepPink },
               new ItemVM() { Text = "Acht", Color = Colors.Turquoise },
               new ItemVM() { Text = "Gute", Color = Colors.Silver },
               new ItemVM() { Text = "Nacht", Color = Colors.Orange }
           };

       public ItemVM this[int i, int j]
       {
           get { return Items[i * 3 + j]; }
           set { Items[i * 3 + j] = value; }
       }
   }
   ```
4. `App.xaml` делаем пустым, окно сначала оснащаем VM'кой, а показываем лишь потом:

   ```
   <Application x:Class="SO8WPF.App"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   </Application>
   ```

   ```
   public partial class App : Application
   {
       MainVM mainVM = new MainVM();

       protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnStartup(e);
           new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM }.Show();
       }
   }
   ```

Вуаля! У нас получилась вот такая картинка:

[image: Uniform grid]

---

Для случая, когда с объектом по клику должно что-нибудь происходить, используются команды. Давайте сделаем, чтобы при клике объект перекрашивался в случайный цвет.

Для начала, нам нужна команда, то есть, имплементация `ICommand`. Я реализую простейший вариант, но вам, возможно, понадобится что-нибудь более интеллектуальное. С `SimpleCommand` можно привязать команду к вашей лямбде или методу.

```
class SimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action onCommand;

    public SimpleCommand(Action onCommand)
    {
        this.onCommand = onCommand;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        onCommand();
    }
}
```

Далее, дополним `ItemVM` командой и её реализацией:

```
public class ItemVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // добавили общий генератор случайных чисел
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    public ItemVM()
    {
        // привязываем команду к методу OnActivation
        Activate = new SimpleCommand(OnActivation);
    }

    string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { if (text != value) { text = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    Color color;
    public Color Color
    {
        get { return color; }
        set { if (color != value) { color = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    // добавили свойство с командой, которая устанавливается в конструкторе
    public ICommand Activate { get; }

    void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    void OnActivation()
    {
        // меняем цвет на случайный
        Color = Color.FromRgb(
            (byte)rnd.Next(256), (byte)rnd.Next(256), (byte)rnd.Next(256));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Окей, VM-часть в порядке. Теперь нужно прикрутить команду к клику. Делается это так.

Во-первых, нужно подключить nuget-пакет `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF` (как обычно, через правый клик по References → Manage NuGet Packages...). Имея это, модифицируем наш шаблон для элемента:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Text}">
    <!-- привязываем команду Activate к событию MouseLeftButtonUp -->
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Activate}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Label.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
    </Label.Background>
</Label>
```

В список пространств имён окна не забываем добавить

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Немного покликав, получаем перекрашенную картинку:

[image: Перекрасили!]

Comment: Ага, а вот теперь и номер ячейки легко прикрутить. [Я же говорил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508523/106) :).

Comment: @VladD, хороший пример, спасибо!

Comment: @andreycha, говорил, а теперь я попробую прикрутить )

Comment: @Lightness удачи ).

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD, неловко уже спрашивать, но я не могу понять как узнать индекс элемента на который я нажал.  Мои попытки сделать это не увенчались успехом. Можете помочь?

Comment: @Lightness: Встречный вопрос (очень серьёзный, не игнорируйте его): зачем вам? Скорее всего, вам это **не нужно**, а нужно что-то другое. От того, что именно вы хотите сделать, многое зависит. Например, если вы хотите выполнить какое-то действие, связанное с элементом, то вам нужен конкретный VM-элемент. Если вы хотите начать drag-n-drop, вам нужен сам UI-элемент, а не его индекс. И т. д. Давайте попробуем сделать _правильно_.

Comment: @VladD, мне это нужно чтобы менять состояние элементов внутри грида. Изменение элементов может происходить не только когда меняется коллекция которая привязана к ним, но и в результате каких то действий пользователя. Поэтому мне нужно знать куда  пользователь нажал.

Comment: @Lightness: Так это делается не так :) Я ж говорил, индекс не нужен. Сейчас выкачу пример.

Comment: @Lightness: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @VladD, Суть я уловил! Но в данном случае каждый Label не знает о существовании других. Допустим я захочу перед установкой цвета Label`а проверить не повторяется ли этот цвет в другом Label, а если повторяется заново сгенерировать новый цвет. Для этого ж мне нужен индекс , чтобы проверить все цвета?

Comment: @Lightness: Не обязательно. Можно каждому `ItemVM` дать ссылку на `MainVM`, и пусть он спрашивает у `MainVM`, использовал ли кто-то ещё такой цвет. А `MainVM` пусть пробежится по всему списку и проверит.

Comment: @Lightness: Как-то так: http://pastebin.com/KUz8VXZX

Comment: @VladD, вот теперь я получил исчерпывающий ответ :) Спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста! Удачи вам на пути изучения MVVM!